# Search with an array of strings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery I'm trying to build a search function. In an input field an user types a string and each word will be put in the variable searchedWords.

The following user search input string:

```
foo bar
```

would convert to

```
let searchedWords = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

---

Now with jQuery I want to search on all strings from the array. All words need to be inside the text of the div with class **'.item'.** I have managed to make this with a single search string. So that

```
let searchedWords = 'foo bar';
```

But that would only match if the div **.item** text would be **foo bar baz** and not **foo baz bar**.

**jQuery**

```
let divs = $('.item');
let searchedWords = ['foo', 'bar']; 

results = divs.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($.trim(searchedWords.toLowerCase())) >= 0;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">foo BAZ bar</div>
<div class="item">bar</div> 
<div class="item">baz/div>
```

**Expected result would be**

```
<div class="item">foo BAZ bar</div>
```

**Actual result**

```
no results...
```

As the user can search on a a string with more words (dynamic) I can't simply hardcode

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($.trim(searchedWords[0].toLowerCase())) >= 0 && 
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($.trim(searchedWords[1].toLowerCase())) >= 0

// ... etc
```

---

So I'm not sure how to search on multiple words with the jQuery filter function.

Comment: The found elements must contain ALL the words?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes the found elements should contain all words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) across the array of words and check the contents of the elements contain *every* word in the list.

```js
let divs = $('.item');
let searchedWords = ['foo', 'bar']; 

var results = divs.filter(function() {
    return searchedWords.every( word => $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) >= 0);
});    

console.log(results.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">foo BAZ bar</div>
<div class="item">bar</div> 
<div class="item">baz</div>
```

Comment: The solution works if the values are `default` as in example above (`<div class="item">foo BAZ bar</div>`). How do I carry out the same **search** when a value (string) is input at runtime? For example, user keying in string sets in a blank _input_ field. Thanks.

Comment: Nope! I am sorry this doesn't seem to work. I keep getting error `Uncaught TypeError: divs.filter is not a function at HTMLInputElement.`. Could you please let me have some pointer to solve the riddle?

Comment: Okay. I got it. As I was passing the value `searchedWords` as a list of words, and not as an **array** I was running into the aforesaid error. I had to change the list to an array. And it worked.